# Entity Framework Transactions - Not Setting Isolation Level

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope

When I make a call down to my business/data access layer I am passing a transaction like this:

```
TransactionOptions tso = new TransactionOptions();
tso.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tso);

using (var tx = ts)
{
     // Actual Code Here
}
```

The problem I am having is that in MSSQL I see there are some sessions with an isolation level of ReadUncommitted and some with ReadCommitted.  In some cases I am getting deadlocks.  Is EF not honoring my options?

Comment: Maybe you can set timeout to `TransactionOptions`. When it encounter dead lock, a volunteer transaction will be picked based on timeout.